# Where are the default Razor cshtml namespaces defined?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config

By default the following appear in code generated by Razor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.WebPages;
```

Where do these come from? I have looked in the machine.config and root-level web.config and it's not in there.

I have verified I can *add* to that list by using:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        .... etc
```

And I'm guessing I might be able to remove using `<clear/>`...but I'm curious to know where they come from to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

It appears these default namespace are hard coded in [WebPageRazorHost.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/WebPageRazorHost.cs) and [MvcWebPageRazorHost.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Razor/MvcWebPageRazorHost.cs) (links to Github).

The former adds all the namespaces in the constructor (including `System.Web.WebPages.Html`), and the latter removes it, using a method called `GetRidOfNamespace`(!)

I tried calling `<clear/>` but sadly/surprisingly it had no effect.

`NamespaceImports` is a public member of `RazorEngineHost` so hopefully one can tweak it in code.

Comment: links are dead.